# Banned 010 ServletResponse.setContentType() to Replace by the ESAPI HTTPUtilities.setCurrentHTTP()

Tags: response, esapi

To set a ServletResponse ContentType you can, for example, implement this ServletResponse.setContentType('text/plain') or ServletResponse.setContentType('text/html') for HTML. But this statement should be replaced by using the ESAPI library like ESAPI.httpUtilities.setContentType() to address potential vulnerability. According to the org.owasp.esapi APIs document (as I understood), the org.owasp.esapi Interface HTTPUtilities setContentType() doesn't allow you to switch from 'text/plain' to 'text/html' programmatically. Is there an ESAPI example or tutorial to show me how to use the ESAPI.httpUtilities.setCurrentHTTP() to change the content type from 'text/plain' to'text/html' programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to this is no:

The reference implementation doesn't allow for programmatic access, it's hard-coded:

https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/sac/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultHTTPUtilities.java

The "setContentType" method is programmed only to pull the property
 value defined in `esapi.properties`:

> Using UTF-8 throughout your stack is highly recommended. That
>   includes your database driver,
>    container, and any other technologies you may be using. Failure to do this may expose you
>    to Unicode transcoding injection attacks. Use of UTF-8 does not hinder internationalization.
>   HttpUtilities.ResponseContentType=text/html; charset=UTF-8

If you want to add that capability you can submit a pull request with your changes at github, or you can write your own one-off for your organization.  I'm not a big fan that the original owners hardcoded this, but that part of the library was written back in 2007.

Comment: Where do you recommend or which package/class that I make the one-off change? I saw there is a comment in the DefaultSecurityConfiguration class.

Comment: getResponseContentType()
Gets the content type for responses used when setSafeContentType() is called. See document link. https://javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html

Comment: But I can't find anywhere in the source code (2.2.0) nor Google search where the setSafeContentType method is defined and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, you would have to subclass the reference implementation DefaultHTTPUtilities to add a setContentType(String headerValue) method. You'd then need to configure ESAPI to use that class instead by changing the 'ESAPI.HTTPUtilities' property in your ESAPI.properties class to reference your custom class.
Furthermore, calling ESAPI.httpUtilities.setContentType() is probably overrated unless you have customized an ESAPI Authenticator interface and are using that custom implementation. (The reference implementation for it is just a toy example.) Then you would to call Authenticator.login() to get much of a benefit from calling ESAPI.httpUtilities.setContentType(value). Of course, you'd have to change the HttpUtilities interface as well to add a new method that takes a header value.
As to whether there is any decent documentation on this? Probably not, at least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed guidance. I will try.